# Is MPI_BYTE better than a derived data type in this case?

Tags: mpi

I'm going to transfer the following structure in memory from one MPI process to another one with a `MPI_Recv`/`MPI_Send` pair.

```
n1 doubles
n1 ints
n2 doubles
n2 ints
...
nX doubles
nX ints
```

where X, and n1, n2, etc are positive integers. This communication is repeated many times, and each time X, and n1, n2, ... can be different from the previous time. I wonder if I should create a derived MPI datatype here, or simply use `MPI_BYTE`. On this site I've seen people discouraging use of `MPI_BYTE` because it makes the code less readable (in their opinion, at least) and also it would be impossible to run the code successfully on heterogeneous systems. Sounds reasonable.

Usually, derived data types are defined once and used many times. In my case, if I use a derived data type it must be defined again and again, since the data structure isn't the same each time. Won't this affect the performance significantly?

Comment: I discourage you from using `MPI_BYTE` for the valid reasons you described. `MPI_Type_commit()` can be expensive, but that should be pretty much nothing compared to the cost of communications, so unless you have data showing that the use of derived datatype introduces a noticeable slowdown in your application, I recommend you avoid using `MPI_BYTE`. But if you choose to do so anyway, make sure you send the data **and** the padding that **might** be added by the compiler between the arrays (since `double` and `int` have different alignments).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, First, I'd like to thank you. You've given informative/helpful comments to many of my questions related to MPI. Second, I guess there would be no padding here, because I copy manually the arrays from different memory locations into the send buffer using `memcpy()`.

Comment: Heterogeneous datatypes are a pain in the behind. Check into`MPI_PACKED` which even has the advantange that you can make the message self-documenting: you store the number `n1`, then the `n1` ints, et cetera.

Comment: Well, if your arrays are a bit everywhere in memory, and unless you have a strong rationale, I strongly encourage you to use a derived datatype to avoid the `memcpy()`: use `MPI_Get_address()` for the offset and `MPI_BOTTOM` for the buffer address.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, after reading your comments I decided to use derived datatypes. But there is one problem: the derived datatype must also be defined on the receiver process (needed in `MPI_Recv()`), but it doesn't know n1, n2, ... integers, which are required for defining the datatype. The sender process has them. It can send them with another `MPI_Send()`, but this probably affects performance.

Comment: You would have the same issue regardless you use `MPI_BYTE` or a derived datatype, right?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, maybe not. The sender process can place n1, n2, ... at the beginning of the send buffer. The receiver can use `MPI_Probe()` to know the amount of memory needed.

Comment: that does not change anything :-)
simply add the (pointer to the) array containing `n1,n2,...` at the beginning of your derived datatype and send it. on the other end, `MPI_Probe()` and receive `MPI_BYTE` => no `memcpy()` on the sender. If you plan to issue `memcpy()` on the receiver, consider sending two messages: the first one containing `n1,n2, ...` and the second the data => receive `n1,n2, ...`, allocate the arrays and create a derived datatype and then receive the datatype.

Comment: I think you missed my comment. Look into `MPI_PACKED`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, I'll do. Thanks.